# What is the $B$-matrix $B$ of orthogonal projection $T$ onto the line in $\mathbb{R}^3$ spanned by $[1,1,1]$?

Tags: linear-algebra

The original question is "Find a basis $\mathcal B$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $\mathcal B$-matrix $B$ of the given linear transformation $T$ is diagonal.
Orthogonal projection $T$ onto the line in $\mathbb{R}^3$ spanned by $[1,1,1]$."

In this case, what does "spanned" mean? When is $B$ diagonal? I know that $B$ is diagonal when $T(V_n)= C_nV_n$.

Comment: I don't understand some parts of the question

Comment: which part don't you understand?

Comment: First of all what's a $B$-matrix? is this just the matrix of $T$ in basis $B$?

Comment: Also what are your $V_n,C_n$? I'm assuming $C_n \in \mathbb{R}$ and $V_n$ is a basis element? But i don't want to assume.

Comment: That's the B- matrix of linear algebra

Comment: can you give me an example of a $B$ matrix?

Comment: Cn is a random constant, and Vn is a vector. For example, x = C1V1+...+CnVn

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56140/discussion-between-mdave16-and-rongeegee).

Comment: @mdave16 From context, “$B$-matrix” most likely means the matrix of $T$ relative to the basis $B$.

Comment: I though as much, we also went to chat and confirmed, I think they are capable of answering their question now.